# casting PyCFunctionWithKeywords in PyMethodDef

Tags: c++, python

Recently I've been wrapping a lot of C++ code in python, and I find this block (taken directly from the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example%5d)) a bit troubling:

```
static PyMethodDef keywdarg_methods[] = {
/* The cast of the function is necessary since PyCFunction values
 * only take two PyObject* parameters, and keywdarg_parrot() takes
 * three.
 */
{"parrot", (PyCFunction)keywdarg_parrot, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS,
 "Print a lovely skit to standard output."},
{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}   /* sentinel */
};
```

The issue is the line which casts `kwarg_parrot`, of type `PyCFunctionWithKeywords` to a `PyCFunction`.

Coming from a C++ background (and given that I am wrapping C++ code), it seems wrong to use a C-style cast. I've tried `static_cast`, and `dynamic_cast`, both of which cause the compiler to complain (with good reason, this really is an unsafe cast in the general sense). The only viable C++ option seems to be`reinterpret_cast`, but so far as I can tell this is a more verbose version of a C-style cast.

Granted, the above *is* wrapped in an `extern "C"` block, so maybe the C way is the correct way. Does anyone have any better ideas? (What I'd really like to see would be a solution that could automatically generate the doc string based on the keywords.)

Unfortunately, solutions like Boost.Python and SWIG are off the table. (I'm working within an ugly framework)

Comment: "C cast" in C++ is called reinterpret_cast, feel free to use it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid the cast (either C-style or reinterpret), because Python wrapping is designed that way. You are supposed to pass on function pointers of various kinds, but you must make them look like a PyCFunction. Deeper down they will be re-interpreted according to the options (such as `METH_VARARGS`) you set.

Comment: How exactly would you like to build the doc string? I did not understand that fully.

Comment: Thanks. It like making libpython able to read intemperate PyCFunctionWithKeywords could be helpful in generating documentation, i.e. rather than having `help(function)` produce `function(...)` followed by the hand written documentation it could actually list the arguments (like it does with python functions). Is there a good reason this hasn't been implemented? (other than that the developers are busy making python great in other ways)

Comment: @Shep Hmmm.. I agree some more automation in the doc string generation would be great. But it would be more complicated than just accepting a `PyCFunctionWithKeywords` as pointer type, right? Because the actual names of the arguments are defined _inside_ the function definition. Simply passing on the correct pointer type would not imply passing on the argument names.

Comment: @jogojapan very good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Python implementation is written in C, not C++.

Thus, libpython code that evaluates `keywdarg_methods[]` is written in C and calls `keywdarg_parrot` via C calling conventions.

If you want C++ style integration with Python, find a way to use boost.python instead. Or perhaps cython.

Comment: No, I have also wrapped a lot of C++ in the same way as Shep. That works, but indeed the type casts are ugly.

Comment: The main issue with Boost.Python is getting it to work with lots of different versions of python and many different computing clusters. We regularly write code which is sent off to a cluster, built there, and then run using a version of python which may lack a corresponding build of Boost.Python. It's often hard enough to point the build system to the Python headers, not to mention build a boost library.

Comment: Perhaps your custom C wrapper is fully justified then.

Answer (score 1):

PyMethodDef is part of the Python C API so I would just use a C cast. It works and it's what all Python extenaions are using. Stay consistent.

Use C++ casts when working with objects that aren't part of the Python API.